# Fix unstable Wifi support on Linux

Tags: linux, arch-linux, wifi, laptop

I bought a new laptop (IdeaPad Flex 5 16ABR8) and the wifi is not always working. After startup most of the time it works just fine at first, but after a while it stops working completely. However, when I use a wifi-USB-drive it works perfectly well. It also stops working when I use a wifi-USB-drive or the LAN and then try to switch back to the internal Wifi-device. I use an arch-based system (arcolinux).

Restarting the network manager did not help.
The `ip` command reveals that the status of the Interface is down:

```
...
2: wlp2s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN group default qlen 1000
...
```

trying to enable the Interface results in the following:

```bash
sudo ip l set wlp2s0 up # enable Interface using ip command
```

```
RTNETLINK answers: Connection timed out
```

## more hardware information (using lshw)

```bash
sudo lshw -C network # get more information about wifi device
```

```
  *-network DISABLED
       description: Wireless interface
       product: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       logical name: wlp2s0
       version: 00
       serial: d0:*:*:*:*:*
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rtw89_8852be driverversion=6.4.10-zen2-1-zen firmware=N/A latency=0 link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11 resources: iomemory:ffffffff0-fffffffef irq:83 ioport:2000(size=256) memory:fd600000-fd6fffff
```

## check for device restrictions (with rfkill)

```bash
rfkill list
```

```
0: ideapad_wlan: Wireless LAN
        Soft blocked: no
        Hard blocked: no
1: ideapad_bluetooth: Bluetooth
        Soft blocked: no
        Hard blocked: no
2: phy0: Wireless LAN
        Soft blocked: no
        Hard blocked: no
9: hci0: Bluetooth
        Soft blocked: no
        Hard blocked: no
```

Comment: check this out https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux-oem-6.1/+bug/2017277